# SQLite c#: Save in-memory db to disk and load from disk to in-memory db?

Tags: c#, sqlite, .net-6.0

I have a NET 6 web service and want to create SQLite database in memory, fill it with data and save it to disk. Also how to load the db from disk to in-memory db?
How to save SQLite in-memory database to disk and load from disk to in-memory in NET 6 c#?

I am searching: how to do it in c# using the freshest Microsoft.Data.Sqlite package

Comment: You can't, you shouldn't want to and you don't appear to have searched.

Comment: I have searched but found samples in c++ using an old SQLite. But I need c# and Microsoft SQLite package, Also, I think it is possible in-memory->disk->in-memory etc.

Comment: @CodeCaster : It is possible I have tested. Works fine in both directions: save in-memory-> disk and load from disk to in-memory

Comment: Feel free to add your answer to the question linked as duplicate, unless it involves copying all table's data, because that's the process outlined by the only answer there already.